# Are there any good applications that can capture a gaming keyboard's extra keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, games

I have a gaming keyboard that has 10 extra keys dedicated for macros. I want to use a couple of those to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> so I get to press only 1 key instead of 2.  I already did a search and found Autokey but it cannot capture any of the extra keys.  Any suggestions?

Comment: S11E04 of the Ubuntu Podcast (UK) talked about how you can program keys on any keyboard(s) (including multiple keyboards, so the E key on keyboard 2 does something different to the E key on keyboard 1) which would probably be a clue. It was awhile ago now so I don't remember accurately (and I remember more liking that a 2nd keyboard can used as a ton of extra [programmable] function keys), but it may contain useful info for you.

Comment: Read `man xev` and use it to see what the keyboard sends when you strike the extra keys.

Comment: @waltinator Unfortunately, xev is not able to capture the keys :(